# While the thread is working, the ordinary variables are flushed to main memory

Tags: java, synchronized

As I understand it, the `memory.a` should be in worker cache memory when the thread is not stopped.
example:

```
public class SynchronizedMemory {
    // non-visible
    private int a = 0;
    public SynchronizedMemory(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    private static void test2() throws InterruptedException {
        SynchronizedMemory memory = new SynchronizedMemory(1);
        Object lock = new Object();
        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("thread1 start................");
            while (memory.a != -1) {
                // When I comment out this line, the thread never jumps out of the loop
                synchronized (lock){}
            }
            System.out.println("thread1 stop................");
        },"thread1").start();
        // wait for thread1 to run
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        new Thread(() -> {
            memory.a = -1;
            // keep the thread alive, prevent it from being completed and refresh the changes back to main memory
            while (true){}
        },"thread2").start();
    }
}
```

As I understand it, the changed value for `memory.a` should be in worker cache memory when `thread2` is not stopped.
When I run the above code, `thread1` exit the loop and finish. This means that the changed value for `memory.a` in `thread2` has been flushed to main memory when `thread2` is still running.
So Can anyone explain this situation?

Comment: What is the purpose of `Thread.sleep(1000);` ? `while (true){` will cause a very tightly run loop which never ends.  Why do you expect anything to change to a non-threadsafe variable?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the effects of synchronized on variable visibility, and I've added a note to the code about the issue you raised.

Comment: Maybe if you did not have `synchronized` the loop would be spinning so tightly that no other thread/process would be able to get any cpu time to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java thread semantics guarantee that things *will* be visible under certain conditions. They give no guarantees about when things will *not* be visible!

Since there is no synchronization between your threads, changes made by one of them may or may not be visible to the other.

Comment: but when I comment out `synchronized (lock){}` in thread1, the thread never jumps out of the loop. In the absence of `synchronized`, it ensures that the variable is invisible to the other. `synchronized ` seems to have some effect on this.

Comment: @YsngzhouLiao: There's a difference between "it happens to be the case that the change isn't visible between threads" and "it *ensures* that the change isn't visible between threads". As Ture has said, there are no guarantees that changes *won't* be visible.